# save whole dataframe in excel and not only the last row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that includes one treatment (group A, B, C) and I loop a function per each group. I then want to save the output of this loop into a new dataset, which I call here NewList. 
However, when I open the excel file, I only get the last column of the new data frame. If I print the new data frame in python I can see all rows. The new data frame should have a y (s_1) for each group in treatment (i). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong when I save the file in excel. Thank you in advance!

````
    import as np
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import ExcelWriter
    from pandas import ExcelFile

    # old dataframe
    df = {'treatment': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
       ..}

    ###### function
    def derivative (t):
        slope =(-fit_B*fit_n*np.exp(-fit_n*t)) - (k*fit_m*np.exp(-fit_m*t))
    return slope

     ###### loop function in dataset based on treatment
    for i, g in df.groupby('treatment'):
        y = derivative(t=10)
        s_1 = pd.DataFrame([y])

###### new data frame
       new_row = {'treatment': i, 'y': s_1.iloc[0, 0]}
       new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(new_row, index=[0]) 
       #I tried to set the index = i, but it did not help. 
       NewList = new_dataframe.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

### why do I get only the last line of the loop in the excel file? I am respecting the loop structure
       writer = ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx')
       NewList.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
       writer.save() ```
````

Comment: You are overwriting writer with each pass of your for loop.

Comment: Use `mode=a`, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Almost done, as now I get all rows (using mode =a). However, the rows are not saved in one sheet, but each of them is saved in a different sheet in the excel file...... Why????